# Workflow Foundation 4: Activity Caching Thread Safety?

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

There are certain places in my code where I invoke an activity using the WorkflowInvoker.Invoke method. I'm having a lot of performance issues because I create an activity every time I need to invoke this.

According [this MSDN Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/02/12/wf4-performance-tip-cache-activities.aspx), I should cache the activity and run the same activity instance rather than creating a new one.

However, my application is multi-threaded. Would it be safe for many threads to use the same instance of the Activity? According to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activity.aspx), it says its not thread-safe, but it looks like the standard message for almost all classes.

I suspect that it should be thread-safe, since the data that the activity uses is stored in a separate context (as Variables and Arguments) rather than a normal instance member of the activity class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found no problems with threads sharing the same Activity instance. This makes sense because data is passed into the activity through the context (rather than the properties of the Activity object). Activity caching significantly improves performance.